# Can I fix mold infestation of around 10 square feet, or do I need pro?

Tags: mold

I have mold under my carpet and part of drywall. Do I need a mold removal pro, or can I do it myself? The water seems to come from a leak in siding.

Comment: Fix the leak, any mold remediation will be short lived.

Comment: While it's possible that the water comes from "a leak in siding" always look up when tracing a leak - roof leaks can travel down walls...

Comment: I tore down the drywall, there is a drainage pipe just where the mold is. Right above the drainage pipe, is where the previous owners had nailed something. Two years ago, when the previous owners moved out, the pulled the nail out, which I believe is the cause of leak. I need to tear down drywall near where nail hole is, to confirm.

Comment: The mold is just 0.5 sq ft, not sure if it is even mold

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree the leak must be fixed first. Hydrogen peroxide is an excellent mold killer. Saturate any areas with a 3% or less solution (test the carpet for color fastness). Hydrogen peroxide will kill the mold and other organics with out the smell of chlorine. If you get a stronger solution of hydrogen peroxide always add the hydrogen peroxide to water not water to the hydrogen peroxide to prevent a bad reaction.  This can be done by a home owner and is easy works quickly. 1 application will usually kill even the toughest gunkies but a second may be needed.